# Hibernate multiple relationships doesn't work

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, annotations, one-to-one

When I create 2 one-to-one relationships in the end only one of the 2 is saved the other one becomes null.

In the sql trace you can see MFUITVOERINGJOIN only saves 2 id's when it should be saving 3 :S

Is there something wrong here?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUD1630651.MFUITVOERING")
public class Uitvoering {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="my_entity_seq_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name="my_entity_seq_gen", sequenceName="HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE_UITVOERING")
@Column(name = "ID")
private int id;

@Column(name = "DATUM")
private String datum;

@Column(name = "SCHOUWBURG")
private String schouwburg;

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)  
@JoinTable(name="MFUITVOERINGJOIN",joinColumns=
{@JoinColumn(name="UITVOERINGID")},
inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="DIRIGENTID")})
private Dirigent dirigent;

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)  
@JoinTable(name="MFUITVOERINGJOIN",joinColumns=
{@JoinColumn(name="UITVOERINGID")},inverseJoinColumns=
{@JoinColumn(name="MUZIEKSTUKID")})
private Muziekstuk muziekstuk;


public Uitvoering(String datum, String schouwburg, Dirigent dirigent, Muziekstuk muziekstuk){
    this.datum = datum;
    this.schouwburg = schouwburg;
    this.dirigent = dirigent;
    this.muziekstuk= muziekstuk;
}

//GETTERS AND SETTERS
```

SQL Trace:

```
Hibernate: select dirigent0_.ID as ID1_3_0_, dirigent0_.KLASSE as KLASSE2_3_0_, dirigent0_.LAND as LAND3_3_0_,  dirigent0_.NAAM as NAAM4_3_0_, dirigent0_.RICHTING as RICHTING5_3_0_ from STUD1630651.MFDIRIGENT dirigent0_ where  dirigent0_.ID=?
Hibernate: select muziekstuk0_.ID as ID1_5_1_, muziekstuk0_.GENRE as GENRE2_5_1_, muziekstuk0_.TITEL as    TITEL3_5_1_, muziekstuk0_1_.INSTRUMENTID as INSTRUME2_0_1_, instrument1_.ID as ID1_4_0_, instrument1_.HOEVEELHEID   as HOEVEELH2_4_0_, instrument1_.NAAM as NAAM3_4_0_ from STUD1630651.MFMUZIEKSTUK muziekstuk0_ left outer join    MFMUZIEKSTUKJOIN muziekstuk0_1_ on muziekstuk0_.ID=muziekstuk0_1_.MUZIEKSTUKID left outer join    STUD1630651.MFINSTRUMENT instrument1_ on muziekstuk0_1_.INSTRUMENTID=instrument1_.ID where muziekstuk0_.ID=?
Hibernate: select HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE_UITVOERING.nextval from dual 
Hibernate: insert into STUD1630651.MFUITVOERING (DATUM, SCHOUWBURG, ID) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into MFUITVOERINGJOIN (MUZIEKSTUKID, UITVOERINGID) values (?, ?)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using [@OneToOne](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-one-mapping-tutorial-using-annotation/) annotation in the wrong place.
As I know one-to-one annotation is used when two tables have `the same primary key` columns.
A one-to-one shows for a record in table A(parrent) there must be one and only one record in table B(child).
 In database level this is achieved by `having a foreign key of A in B table, when this  foreign key column(s) in B table is(are) marked as primary key of B`.
Technically it is not possible to have more than one one-to-one relation in child table.
So in your question `MFUITVOERING` as child table have its owned primary key called ID (field with sequence values). 
 The two foreign keys of `MFUITVOERINGJOIN` in `MFUITVOERING` are representation of `ManyToOne` relationship.
 You need to use [@ManyToOne](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-many-annotation-tutorial/) annotation.